# Turn off flutter shortening of doubles as string

Tags: flutter, dart, types

I have a problem. I am programming an output tracker and when I want to output a double as a string (text), if it ends with a zero at the end, the 0 is simply truncated. Is there a way to turn this off. because it looks pretty bad as text. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You could use [toStringAsFixed](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html).

Comment: Thaks, it works